# Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null when using repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication system for my application.

For that I have created a class(lib) called Auth that extends my UserRepository so I can use the model directly in my auth class.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Lib;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;

class Auth extends UserRepository {
```

Inside my authenticate function that lives in Auth I call findByCredentials function which should return me some user data from the db.

```php
$user = $this->findByCredentials($email, $password);
```

I call this inside my controller to make it run

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    $auth = new Auth();
    $auth->authenticate(null, 'somefakemaik@example.com', '1234');
    return $this->tpl();
}
```

This is my UserRepository which has been auto generated and I added only that one function by far.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function findByCredentials($email, $password)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
            ->andWhere('user.email = :email')
            ->andWhere('user.password = :password')
            ->setParameters([
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password
              ])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

But then I get the error mentioned in the title.

I used the cli/console to generate everything and made sure that my table exists in the database. I'm using a MySQL v5.7 on a linux machine.

I have also configured the config/packages/doctrine.yaml

Contructor of auth class

```php
public function __construct($jwt = null, $email = null, $password = null) {
    $this->jwt = $jwt;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have a `__construct` in your `Auth` class? please show that. But I suspect, that you violate the dependency injection used. Why don't you just add the functions in Auth to your `UserRepository`? In your controller, you probably should add the UserRepository to the function parameter list so it gets injected properly. (Please also show the function header of your controller function / route)

Comment: @Jakumi I have updated the question as you requested. Do you mean that the constructor of Auth class should have this dependency injected?

Comment: The problem is that you create an instance of `Auth` by yourself, and not going through DependencyInjection methods. If you look closely, you will notice that `new Auth()` does not receive any arguments needed by the `__construct()` in your UserRepository class. Follow good practices and re-factor your code a bit and you will be good to go.

Comment: @Artamiel Hi, thanks for answering. Could you please provide me with some resources where I can read more about this stuff. I've tried to inject the RegistryInterface and call parent::__construct() inside my Auth class constructor, but it says "Cannot instantiate interface". The only thing I'm really trying to achieve is to have a small library that has some logic and can perform some simple sql queries and not being a controller at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently removing the advantages of dependency injection.

dependency injection is essentially, that you don't create a service inside your class but instead provide it as a parameter either in the constructor or in the function call(s). (In the symfony framework, you don't usually have to create it at another place, but symfony will take care of providing it for you, unless you explicitly want to call the function/constructor ... which is why you usually don't.)

One example would be the controller, where the `Request $request` (type-hinted) is provided by the framework. Technically you can have almost any type-hinted class in there, as long as the framework (more specifically the container) knows that class and how to generate an/the instance of it. That a container generates the dependencies for you, is connected to auto-wiring or auto-configuration, and it's very very convenient. (Docs for symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

In your specific example: I would advise against extending the `UserRepository` and propose two better alternatives:

#### move it inside your `UserRepository`

if you want to extend the UserRepository, and that UserRepository is already specific and somewhat unique to your project, why not put the "extension" right inside the UserRepository? I really can't think of a very good reason not to do this. However ...

#### the `Auth` service.

Since some major preparation goes into creating a Repository on the side of doctrine and there are some singleton-like dependencies involved (the registry, the connection, ...) and burrowed somewhere, go the way of the auto-wiring/auto-configuring framework and make the `UserRepository` a parameter of your `Auth` service:

```
class Auth {
    /** @var UserRepository */
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository) {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function authenticate(...) {
        /* some logic that can use $this->userRepository */
    }
}
```

Important remark: You have jwt, email, password as parameters to your Auth. This makes a semantic difference: Either it is a Service that authenticates users, in which case jwt, email and password should definitely not be part of the constructor, because then it would be the authentication for ONE user, the one for which it is created ... which provides close to no benefit. Otherwise it should receive those parameters on the authenticate call - which makes more sense in my opinion.

IF however, you are doing some elaborate authentication protocol where you communicate with an external server that needs some additional credentials ON TOP of the user's credentials (user auth as a service or whatever), then my argument is void and you should learn how to define Auth's credentials in the services.yaml.

But I suspect, that's not the case. It's probably a good idea to think about state for a moment. In general, find out, what is actually necessary to construct a service, and those things add to the constructor. When the service has to DO something, that belongs as parameters in the service's methods.

### fixing your controller

Creating an `Auth` by yourself is quite inconvenient, because you would have to rebuild many functionality that symfony's dependency injection + auto wiring + auto configuring already provides. The clean way is to inject what you need.

I'll repeat your index route here, and add some commentary below

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $auth = new Auth();
    $auth->authenticate(null, 'somefakemaik@example.com', '1234');
    return $this->tpl();
}
```

although not strictly required, it is common to name the route-functions of a controller `[something]Action`, so `indexAction`. Secondly, you apparently don't use the `Request`, so you should remove it. Thirdly, add either the `UserRepository` or `Auth` to your method header (depending on which alternative you chose):

```
// this goes into your controller

// or: public function indexAction(UserRepository $userRepository) { 
public function indexAction(Auth $auth) {
    $auth->authenticate(/** ... your parameters ... */);
    return $this->tpl(); // <-- what's this? ;o)
}
```